# How to get list of all the servers to which discord owner is connected

Tags: discord

Is there any API to get list of all the servers to which the discord owner(user) is connected.

I want to write a bot to manage all the servers connected to discord owner's account.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeremy mentioned you can use  https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds if logged in as the user you're trying to get guilds of. A total list of Guilds isn't possible to get for other users though, you'll only get mutual/shared guilds displayed for others.